# SMD identification SOT23 "t" "7" symbol

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I tried to identify the component marked with "t 30" the SOT23 package. I looked for the "t" of "7" symbol in this list

[image]

and also tried smd marking search engine but couldn't find it.

[image]

Comment: Could be [PDTC114Y](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PDTC114Y_SER.pdf) NPN transistor?

Comment: It might be but I couldn't find a meaning for the "t" symbol but the specs are what i expect so this could be it

Comment: The logo can be one of the unpopular Chinese brands'.

Answer (score 2):

The small "t" in the marking is typical from Nexperia. It is the assembly location code. So "30" is the significant model marking.

I found the matching marking in the following datasheet of PDTC114YU (SOT-323 package).

https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PDTC114YU.pdf

And here is a picture of it :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking after the sign, but I could not find this item. But to my eye, it will be NPN or N-MOSFET transistor.
The bottom right foot looks like it was connected to GND. The lower left leg as if it received a control signal (narrow path). In contrast, the upper leg as if it had a connected load (wider path).
It looks like the NPN or N-MOSFET transistor as a key function.

[NPN Transistor](https://www.google.com/search?q=npn%20sot23&client=firefox-b-1&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=duddpSLrHxQXvM%253A%252CzyPhkS3vOB06QM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kTJNyCnbAnAOkYzgOO7yUfaUQnUaQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJlcb9n9TfAhWLwcQHHR1IDeQQ9QEwBHoECAUQDA#imgrc=duddpSLrHxQXvM:)

[N-MOSFET Transistor](https://www.google.com/search?q=MOSFET%20Sot23&client=firefox-b-1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI-NXroNTfAhUq7YMKHfDrD6MQ_AUIDigB&biw=1599&bih=788)